# Linking multiple arrays after parsing from XML

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have parsed many differend xml to check, if - for example - a document is online or not and putting it into an array and "echo" the online documents this way:

```
<?php
    //  

//Array

 $externdoc[123] = "Example 1"; 

 $externdoc[456] = "Example 2"; 

 $externdoc[789] = "Example 3"; 

 $externdoc[2562] = "Example 4"; 

 $externdoc[78545] = "Example 5"; 

// func

foreach($externdoc as $nr => $name)
{
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.example.com/docs.php?live_id=".$nr);

    if($xml->liveDocs->download!=0)
    {
        echo 'Download: '. $xml->liveDocs->download.'    '.$name.;
    }

}


?>
```

**Now here is the interesting part of my question. I would like to link each array with a different URL like this:**

```
<?php
    //  

//Array

 $externdoc[123] = "Example 1"; 
 $externdoc [url]  = 'http://www.example.com/docs/1.php';

 $externdoc[456] = "Example 2"; 
 $externdoc [url]  = 'http://www.example.com/docs/2.php';

 $externdoc[789] = "Example 3"; 
 $externdoc [url]  = 'http://www.example.com/docs/3.php';

 $externdoc[2562] = "Example 4"; 
 $externdoc [url]  = 'http://www.example.com/docs/4.php';

 $externdoc[78545] = "Example 5"; 
 $externdoc [url]  = 'http://www.example.com/docs/5.php';

// func

foreach($externdoc as $nr => $name)
{
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.example.com/docs.php?live_id=".$nr);

    if($xml->liveDocs->download!=0)
    {
        echo '<a href="HOW DO I LINK IT?"> Download: '. $xml->liveDocs->download.'    '.$name.;
    }

}

?>
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a composite for each entry, the first exemplary:

```
$externdoc[123] = array("Example 1", 'http://www.example.com/docs/1.php');
```

Inside the foreach you can then refer to the title *and* the URL:

```
foreach($externdoc as $nr => $entry)
{
    list($name, $url) = $entry; # name and URL in a variable of it's own
    ...
```

Hope this is helpful, this is basically to create an [array <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) of arrays. Instead of using one array per entry/item, you can also use [`stdClass` objects <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) which can have multiple properties as well (like an array can have multiple key/value pairs).